# Sorting lines within paragraphs

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I need to change the order of the lines of the paragraphs in a text file where each paragraph has this structure:

```
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>
<user>some name</user>
```

I need the line with `<user>some name</user>` to be the first one in each paragraph. I.e.:

```
<user>some name</user>
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>
```

How do I accomplish this, in awk, sed, etc.?

Comment: How are the paragraphs separated? Are the `<foo>...</foo>` parts entirely on one line?

Comment: "paragraph" has a very specific meaning to awk - it means records separated by one or more blank lines. Is that what you have? Add a second record (block of lines) so we can see what separates them in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming paragraphs are separated with one or more blank lines you can do this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; OFS=FS="\n"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                                    if($i~/user/) {$1=$i OFS $1;
                                                   $i=""}}1' text

<user>some name</user>
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>

<user>some name</user>
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>

<user>some name</user>
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>
```

you can fine tune the pattern "user" for a more accurate match but works for the sample input.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perl can do custom sorting of the lines in a paragraph

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -lane '
  print 
    join "\n", 
    sort {
      if    ($a =~ /<user>/) { -1 }
      elsif ($b =~ /<user>/) { +1 }
      else                   { $a cmp $b }
    }
    @F
' file
```

Notes:

- `-00` read the file in paragraphs (separated by one or more blank lines)
- `-F'\n'` uses a newline as the field separator, and `-a` splits the lines of the paragraph into the perl array `@F`
- the custom sorting block sorts lines with `<user>` first, and all other lines lexically.

one-liner-ized:

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -lape'$_=join"\n",sort{$a=~/<user>/?-1:$b=~/<user>/?1:$a cmp $b}@F' file
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
sed '/<body>/{:a;N;/<user>/!ba};s/\(.*\)\n\(<user>.*\)/\2\n\1/' file
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that the `<user>...</user>` fragment appears on a line by itself, and that apart from these `<user>` lines, the other lines should NOT be re-ordered.  Otherwise it is quite robust, efficient, and adaptable.

```
awk '
  function p(  i) { for(i=0;i<n;i++) print s[i]; n=0; }
  /<user>/ {print; p(); next;}
  NF==0 {p(); print; next;}
  {s[n++]=$0}
  END { p() }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT be all you need:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v OFS='\n' '{a[$2]=$0} !(NR%3){print a["user"], a["body"], a["date"]}' file
<user>some name</user>
<body>blah blah</body>
<date>some date</date>
```

It just depends what's in the parts of the input file that you haven't shown us.

Comment: This works, thank you. I like its simplicity. How can I make it keep the blank line between paragraphs? (sorry I didn't specify there was one in my original post)

Comment: trivially but you still haven't updated your post and you've already selected an answer so good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Ed. All the suggested solutions provided, except yours, correctly interpret the concept of "paragraph", as "there's a blank line separating groups of lines", so they all work perfectly for what I needed. I'm new here and so I hadn't realised how grumpy one might get if they don't get their answers "voted", "liked" or whatever other ego-boosting ticks people might be after online. Cheers.

Comment: You greatly overestimate the value of points. No-one cares. The reasons I won't put more time/effort into this answer are that a) you aren't willing to put your time/effort into editing your question to provide the critical missing requirement, b) having an answer to an unclear question is not useful to the community since the next person with the same question will not be able to find this answer, and c) since you have already decided which answer you plan to use, my putting more effort into this one would be wasted time even for your benefit alone.